# Run PM2 cron only on a scheduled time

Tags: node.js, cron, pm2

I run one of my node.js command using the following command:

```
pm2 start sample.js --cron "0 1 * * *" -- SAMP
```

But the problem is this program run twice. First one is when I execute the command and send one is at 1:00 AM(Which we want).

So my query is how can set the cron so that this program runs at only once (At 1:00 AM only).

Comment: Looks like the --cron option specifies when to _restart_ a running app. Not when to start it. http://pm2.keymetrics.io/docs/usage/pm2-doc-single-page/#options

Answer (score 1):

My suggestion to you is to use crontab for this task. This is exactly what cron was designed for, and not what pm2 was designed for.

As the comment above states, the `--cron` option only specifies when the app should be *restarted*, `--cron` cannot be used to schedule the running of an app. In the cases where we need to run a node app on a specific time table and don't need all of the fancy pm2 capabilities of auto-restarting and clustering, we simply use crontab.